# Is the switch automorphism inner for continuous-trace $C^*$-algebras?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

If $R$ is a commutative ring, and $A$ is an Azumaya algebra over $R$, then the switch (or flip, or exchange, etc.) automorphism of $A\otimes_R A$, given by $a\otimes b\mapsto b\otimes a$, is inner: it is the conjugation by the so-called Goldman element $g\in (A\otimes_R A)^\times$. This element is an important feature of Azumaya algebras, and can be defined as the element corresponding to the reduced trace of $A$ under the natural $R$-module identification $A\otimes_R A\simeq \operatorname{End}_R(A)$ (where the reduced trace is seen as a $R$-linear map $A\to R\subset A$).

Now in the context of $C^*$-algebras, if $R$ is a commutative $C^*$-algebra (corresponding to some $C_0(T)$), my understanding is that the equivalent of Azumaya algebras over $R$ are the continuous-trace algebras $A$ with spectrum $T$. For instance, $A$ is locally Morita-equivalent to $R$; it also has a Morita-inverse: $A\otimes_T \bar{A}$ is Morita-equivalent to $R$, where $\otimes_T$ is the balanced tensor product relative to the spectrum $T$.

The theory of continuous-trace $C^*$ algebras has many similarities to the theory of Azumaya algebras, but I haven't been able to determine if they share this property:

> Is there a "Goldman element" $g\in (A\otimes_T A)^\times$ such that the conjugation by $g$ is the switch automorphism? If so, can this element be chosen unitary?

I would be fine with restricting to the case where $T$ is compact (so $R$ has a unit).

The algebraic construction of the element can almost, but not quite exactly, be imitated, since $A\otimes_T A$ can identified as a $C_0(T)$-module with $\mathcal{K}(Y_A)$ where
$$Y_A = \{a\in A\,|\, (t\mapsto tr(aa^*)(t))\in C_0(T)\}$$
is a right Hilbert $C_0(T)$-module. This is similar to $A\otimes_R A\simeq \operatorname{End}_R(A)$ in the algebraic case, but there is no obvious "trace" element in $\mathcal{K}(Y_A)$.